# Connecting Ruby to mySQL on windows

Tags: mysql, ruby, windows

I am new to Ruby.
I am using Ruby 1.9.3 on Windows 7.I am trying to connect to mySQL I have been stuck for 2 days/

I have installed the mySQL gem by using the command:

```
gem install mysql
```

This reported:
Successfully installed mysql-2.9.1-x86-mingw32

But when I try to connect with the code below I get the error message

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot 
 load such file -- mysql/mysql_api (LoadError)
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.9.1-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql.rb:6:in 
  `rescue i n <top (required)>'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.9.1-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql.rb:2:in `
  <top (required)>'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in
  require
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
  from C:/ruby database stuff/connect1.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

My code is here:

```
 require 'mysql'

 begin
    con = Mysql.new 'localhost', 'user', 'pass*'
    puts con.get_server_info
    rs = con.query 'SELECT VERSION()'
    puts rs.fetch_row    

rescue Mysql::Error => e
   puts e.errno
   puts e.error

ensure
  con.close if con
end
```

Comment: Can you connect to mysql server with mysql console??...is your mysql server running as a service??

Comment: Yes mySQL is running and I can connect to it.  This is problem with the ruby or the ruby gem